# mysql query to pick up distinct values for users and related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named "games".
In this table there are a few fields. The relevant fields are
    user1
    user2
    round1
    round2
    round3

The fields user1 and user2 are integers/ids that of course are taken from the table "user" (with id and name as fields).

The fields 
    round1
    round2
    round3 
are integer/ids taken from the table "questions".

Now what I need is to create an sql query that will fetch IDs from the table "questions" BUT only those question-ids that have NOT been used by the users yet.

My idea is to make something like (when the users that are playing have he IDs equals to 1 AND 2):

```
select from questions where id NOT IN (select round1 from questions where (user1 = 1 OR user1 = 2 OR user2 = 1 OR user2 = 2)  )
```

Im not sure this query really look good and is optimized. However, it is not complete yet. I actually need to put 2 more WHERE criterias that look as the one above with round1 substituted by round2 and round3. So finally it could look like:

```
select from questions 
where id NOT IN (select round1 from questions where 
         (user1 = 1     OR user1 = 2 OR user2 = 1 OR user2 = 2)  )
and id NOT IN (select round2 from questions where 
         (user1 = 1 OR user1 = 2 OR user2 = 1     OR user2 = 2)  )
and id NOT IN (select round3 from questions where 
         (user1 = 1 OR user1 = 2 OR user2 = 1     OR user2 = 2)  )
```

Also, I probably would need to add "distinct" before round1/round2/round3.

So, do you think there is a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: curiosity for you...is this running as an ongoing script, or is it a one time run only to find the unused questions?  Where in / not in (select...) performs really poorly in MySQL and there are other ways (left joins where null / not null)

Comment: Well, actually this query is running each time a user plays a match with another user. So this could in theory happens very often depending on how many matches are played. is that bad?

Comment: If the data set is big enough you'll hit performance issues.  I'm going to post two answers in my answer...will leave it up to you to determine which one has a better query plan and executes faster for you.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I will compare performance.

Comment: What is everyone talking about? This is WRONG, WRONG, WRONG. See normalization!

Comment: How could it look like strawberry? A table with rounds? Could you give some hints? Would this really be much better performance wise? Table could grow a lot.Thanks.

Comment: First see normalization. Then try to normalize your design. Then get back to us - and we'll help if we can.

Comment: @Strawberry - Well duh, most SQL questions on SO can be answered with 'normalize your datamodel', but it's usually quite rare that you can (inherited from previous owner being the usual reason). Sometimes you have to deal with what you are given regardless.

Comment: @user3355182 - round1 round2 round3 in a table like this isn't 'normalized'. If you are still in a place where you can alter your tables, do look up normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below using `UNION`

```
select * from questions 
where id NOT IN (
select distinct round1 
from questions 
where user1 in (1,2) OR user2 in (1,2)

UNION

select distinct round2 
from questions 
where user1 in (1,2) OR user2 in (1,2)

UNION

select distinct round3 
from questions 
where user1 in (1,2) OR user2 in (1,2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from questions 
  where ID not in (select round1 from games 
                    union all 
                   select round2 from games 
                    union all 
                   select round 3 from games)
```

That will return all questions that are not listed in the round1 or round2 or round3 fields out of games.  Logic is use a query to build up the list of question ID's that are used in games table as a subquery (I'm using unions since you have 3 fields) and then include that in the where not in () clause

MySQL handles where in() or not in() clauses like this pretty poorly and I don't recommend using this logic as an ongoing script...for one shot with low amounts of data, it works.

added : include where clauses in the subselect (at each union) to narrow it down to userID = 1 or 2

Answer 2:  where not in () and where in () can be rewritten as joins...and it's usually substantially quicker than doing it as a where not in statement (and even more so in MySQL, the engine here does not handle subselects in where statements well).  Left joins produce nulls when nothing is found in the corresponding table

```
select q.*
from questions q
left join games g1 on g1.round1 = q.id
left join games g2 on g2.round2 = q.id
left join games g3 on g3.round3 = q.id
where g1.round1 is null and g2.round2 is null and g3.round3 is null
```

Hope I got that right...you are joining the questions to the games table, left join will produce nulls when it's not found...

Give that a try, compare the execution plans and see how the performance is on both.